# Replacing count by percentage in R

Tags: r, statistics, data, data-analysis, homework

I have the following code :

```
  mutate( bmi = Gewicht / (Körpergröße/100)^2 ) %>%
  filter( Lebensalter >= 18 )%>%
  filter(!is.na(bmi))%>%
  group_by(Geschlecht, Ethnie)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Ratio))%>%
  mutate (Poor = Ratio < 1.3)%>%
  mutate (Adipös= bmi>=30)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Poor))%>%
  ggplot+
  geom_histogram(aes( y= Poor, fill=Adipös), stat = "count")+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)
```

which gives me this table: [image]

How can I get the percentage for each true and false for poor and adipös? E.g. 20% of male poor African American are also "Adipös" (overweight)? So instead of the bars showing the count I would have the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I think you can just add `position = "fill"` like this:

```
ggplot+
  geom_histogram(aes( y= Poor, fill=Adipös), position = "fill")+
  facet_grid(Ethnie~Geschlecht)
```

If I'm not mistaken `stat='count'` is optional.

Comment: When i replace count by fill I get the error message:

Comment: Error in `check_subclass()`:
! Can't find `stat` called 'fill'
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::geom_histogram(aes(y = Poor, fill = Adipös), stat = "fill")
 2. ggplot2::layer(...)
 3. ggplot2:::check_subclass(stat, "Stat", env = parent.frame())

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake: it's `position='fill'`. I'm editing my answer.